# Driver Power State Failure BSOD

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, bsod, dump, minidumps

I've had quite a few BSODs on this almost-one-year-old Windows 8.1 Asus laptop. I thought it was my Nvidia driver's fault, but apparently not, though when I reverted to an older version, no BSOD happened for a few months.
After so many of them, I got tired, so I decided to ask for your help.
Here's the zip file with the last three minidumps:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/26q1e727sudic2a/DMP.zip

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you analyze the dumps? What did you find out so far?

Comment: I'm terrible at analyzing dumps. When I opened WinDBG, all I read was gibberish, hence me asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crash is related to ACPI issues for the *Intel(R) Xeon(R) processor E3 - 1200 v3/4th Gen Core processor PCI Express x16 Controller* (`PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0C01&SUBSYS_177D1043`)

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: ffffe000e1eaa060, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: fffff8031a33d960, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: ffffe000e1e994a0, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  6.3.9600.18090 (winblue_ltsb.151014-0600)

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  N551JX

SYSTEM_SKU:  ASUS-NotebookSKU

SYSTEM_VERSION:  1.0       

BIOS_VERSION:  N551JX.202

BIOS_DATE:  01/16/2015

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.14321.1024 amd64fre

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt!PopIrpWatchdogBugcheck
02 nt!PopIrpWatchdog
03 nt!KiRetireDpcList
04 nt!KiIdleLoop


IMAGE_VERSION:  6.3.9600.17238

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_ACPI_IMAGE_pci.sys

BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_ACPI_IMAGE_pci.sys

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x9f_3_acpi_image_pci.sys


0: kd> !irp ffffe000e1e994a0
Irp is active with 6 stacks 4 is current (= 0xffffe000e1e99648)
 No Mdl: No System Buffer: Thread 00000000:  Irp stack trace.  
     cmd  flg cl Device   File     Completion-Context
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>[IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_SET_POWER(2)]
            0 e1 ffffe000e1f0e740 00000000 fffff801d9a05b30-ffffe000e1eb9190 Success Error Cancel pending
           \Driver\ACPI pci!PciBusPowerUpCompletion
            Args: 00000000 00000001 00000001 00000000
 [IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_SET_POWER(2)]
            0 e1 ffffe000e1eb9040 00000000 fffff8031853bc0c-ffffe000e1e97f08 Success Error Cancel pending
           \Driver\pci  nt!PopRequestCompletion
            Args: 00000000 00000001 00000001 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-ffffe000e1e97f08    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0: kd> !podev ffffe000e1eaa060
Device object is for:
  DriverObject e1f19c60
Current Irp 00000000 RefCount 0 Type 00000022 AttachedDev ffffe000e1f0e740 DevFlags 00001040
Device queue is not busy.
Device Object Extension: ffffe000e1eaa778:
PowerFlags: 00000040 =>SystemState=0 DeviceState=4
Dope: 00000000:
0: kd> !devstack ffffe000e1f0e740
  !DevObj           !DrvObj            !DevExt           ObjectName
  ffffe000e1eb9040  \Driver\pci        ffffe000e1eb9190  
> ffffe000e1f0e740  \Driver\ACPI       ffffe000e05f47f0  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffe000e1f0e710

  ffffe000e1eaa060  \Driver\pci        ffffe000e1eaa1b0  Cannot read info offset from nt!ObpInfoMaskToOffset

!DevNode ffffe000e1eb97a0 :
  DeviceInst is "PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0C01&SUBSYS_177D1043&REV_06\3&11583659&1&08"
  ServiceName is "pci"
```

In the power settings of windows, disable [power saving of PCI Express](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/292971-pcie-link-state-power-management-turn-off-windows.html).

[image]

Comment: Hey, that's cool. I never managed to figure out how to analyze BSODs more than `!analyze -v`. How did you learn that? Is there a good book on using WinDbg to analyze blue screens?

Comment: And, if I may ask, do you have some sample dumps like the ones provided by the OP together with a solution like this?

Comment: @ThomasWeller reading msdn pages about the crashes, they show some steps to do. the rest: learning by trying

Comment: So, uhh... Another BSOD. After I followed your instructions to a T.
http://www.mediafire.com/download/xmau4dcx9cdd6s7/dump.zip
Here's the new dump. Honestly I'm extremely tired of this.

Comment: still the same ACPI issue. update the BIOS/UEFI to 207, you use the older 202, maybe it fixes the issue